# Can I use Java xunit to test applications coded in C#?

Tags: java, c#, xunit

Im wondering if Java code can be used in xunit to write unit tests against code that is c#. Is this possible?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: Maybe look into [IKVM](https://www.ikvm.net/).

Comment: That could be feasible, but hardly something that you should consider doing. When it comes down to unit testing, better keep the test and the code on the same language. I mean, why you would want your C# dev write software in C# and have them test it using Java?

Comment: Why....for no other reason than I am versed in Java and in QA. We have brought on a third party group for a release and they use xunit. So i was wanting to know if I could get around having to come up to speed on C# to support the release effort. Thanks for the feedback. I was afraid of the answers but kind of figured what they would be.